# Is there playbook-level memory storage for ansible? (unserializable !)

Tags: performance, ansible

During the execution of a playbook, does Ansible provide some kind of in-memory storage that remains alive and intact in between task executions ? That is, being the very same object, in the very same memory location.

My use case is an hours long running playbook, doing frequent queries to an external system from within custom plugins. Lots of time could be saved if there was a way to put the connection object in a shared memory variable. Added to that, some queries are deterministic. Which means the results could be cached into a shared memory variable too.

There must be something like it somewhere. Otherwise Ansible wouldn't be able to reuse ssh connections.

Comment: Regarding "_... doing frequent queries to an external system from within custom plugins. Lots of time could be saved if there was a way to put the connection object in a shared memory variable._", can you provide more information and details regarding this? Maybe sample code snippets?

Comment: "_My use case is an hours long running playbook ..._" wouldn't that be a job for [Asynchronous actions and polling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this solves your problems completely, but there is one thing you should definetely give a shot.

You can utilize `redis` caching for facts gathering. Especially in time consuming playbooks, atomic reading the facts from a cache server can significantly decrease play times. It can be enabled in yor `ansible.cfg` file like below:

```
   [defaults]
   fact_caching=redis
   fact_caching_timeout = 7200
   fact_caching_connection = localhost:6379:0
```

You can refer to [this](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-fact-cache-redis) guide for this feature.

Comment: Isn't this going to serialize the data ?

Comment: At least a good hint about [How to cache Ansible facts with Redis](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-fact-cache-redis) ...

Answer (score 0):

> *During the execution of a playbook, does Ansible provide some kind of in-memory storage that remains alive and intact in between task executions?*

In general that is what [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) are for. See also [`set_fact` module – Set host variable(s) and fact(s)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html).

> *Like registered variables, facts are stored in memory by default.*

Whereby [Caching facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts)

> *... unlike registered variables, facts can be gathered independently and cached for repeated use. With cached facts, you can refer to facts from one system when configuring a second system, even if Ansible executes the current play on the second system first.*

---

> *Otherwise Ansible wouldn't be able to reuse SSH connections.*

The parameters to [Connecting to hosts: behavioral inventory parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters) are related to the [Ansible inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#adding-variables-to-inventory). These are not gathered as facts after connecting to the Remote System but available before within the inventory in-memory. There are also possibilities to have a [Dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html). See also [Developing dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html).